# Induced Electric Field (E-field) Around a Toroidal Coil or Toroidal Cylinder Coil

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Im trying to figure out the formula/formulas that describes the induced electric field around a toroidal coil or a toroidal cylinder in case dB/dt=!0. If I remember correctly there was a very good paper that I found a few years ago in which the Faraday's law of induction was solved for a toroid in which there were three different solutions/formulas for the E-field for the three different regions of the coil (inside the hole in the middle, within the torus itself and outside of the torus) but I simply cant find it again. In this formula the E field was a function of the radius from the axis of the torus and of course the function of the rate of change in the magnetic field.
What Im researching is a form of linear induction accelerator in which an ion beam would be accelerated through the hole in the middle of a toroid coil via the change in the magnetic flux in the torus. Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you find that paper?